# VLC snapshot with just the filename?

Tags: vlc-media-player

I've learnt that its possible to have the VLC snapshots save with a specific prefix. I want the snapshots to be saved with just the video name (the filename, not the title) (not including the sequential numbering or anything else). Is this something possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This wil *almost* give you what you want: In VLC *Advanced Preferences*, under *Video*, set the *Video snapshot file prefix* to `$N-`. Set the checkbox for *Use sequential numbers instead of timestamps*.

[image: VLC Include filename]

Snapshots will be saved in the format *filename-nnnnn*, where *nnnnn* is a 5-digit sequence number, starting *00001*. Sorry, I do not know of a way to completely eliminate that suffix sequence number, and likely VLC does not allow that, because it would force subsequent snapshots to overwrite the previous.

Comment: Thanks for the input